# How to guarantee uniqueness of a record using a complex key?

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a simple table, with 3-rd foreign keys. How to make it impossible to re-record with the same values for these three keys? Create a complex key based on them?

And how to do it in the Workbench environment, just specify additionally each foreign key as a primary key?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i get your question, you are looking to enforce uniqueness in the columns (user_id,position_id,organization_id).

Assuming that at least one of the columns is (not null). If you were to create a unique index on the three columns it should work.

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name
   ON Employers(user_id,position_id,organization_id);